# Handling months in python datetimes

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.4

I have a function which gets the start of the month before the datetime provided:

```
def get_start_of_previous_month(dt):
    '''
    Return the datetime corresponding to the start of the month
    before the provided datetime.
    '''
    target_month = (dt.month - 1)
    if target_month == 0:
        target_month = 12
    year_delta = (dt.month - 2) / 12
    target_year = dt.year + year_delta

    midnight = datetime.time.min
    target_date = datetime.date(target_year, target_month, 1)
    start_of_target_month = datetime.datetime.combine(target_date, midnight)
    return start_of_target_month
```

However, it seems very convoluted.  Can anyone suggest a simpler way?  I am using python 2.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `timedelta(days=1)` offset of the beginning of *this* month:

```
import datetime

def get_start_of_previous_month(dt):
    '''
    Return the datetime corresponding to the start of the month
    before the provided datetime.
    '''
    previous = dt.date().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return datetime.datetime.combine(previous.replace(day=1), datetime.time.min)
```

`.replace(day=1)` returns a new date that is at the start of the current month, after which subtracting a day is going to guarantee that we end up in the month before. Then we pull the same trick again to get the first day of *that* month.

Demo (on Python 2.4 to be sure):

```
>>> get_start_of_previous_month(datetime.datetime.now())
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0)
>>> get_start_of_previous_month(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 21, 12, 23))
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 1, 0, 0)
```